# Best way to store multiple values in MySQL for an ulterior "like %" request?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am running a website with classified ads and I'd like to set up a function which will send an email alert when a new ad matches some patterns.

The idea is to allow the users to store multiples patterns, then perform a SELECT with them:

```
select ad from table where (content LIKE '%this%' OR content LIKE '%that%')
```

Of course, I don't know in advance how many patterns the user will need.

One solution would be to create one line per user and per pattern, and selecting with joining the tables, but I am afraid of the database performance.

I've thought about JSON data but I can't figure out how to do something like that:

```
select ad from table where content like (["this","that"])
```

Or maybe there is a better way?

**Edit**

After viewing the first answers (thank you) I realize I was not clear enough.

The patterns will be also stored in the database, the final request should be something like:

```
select ad from table where content LIKE (select *something* from pattern_table where userId = 123)
```

The question is mainly : what is the best way to store the patterns in pattern_table

Comment: you can use REGEXP  or RLIKE  also.

Comment: You may also look at Full Text Searching. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I have edited the post, as I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**Once try**

```
select ad from table where content REGEXP 'this|that'
```